# Intersection of nef divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbf{C}$ of dimension $n$. Let $D_1,\cdots,D_n$ be nef Cartier divisors on $X$.

Is it true that $(D_1 \cdots D_n)^n \geq D_1^n \cdots D_n^n$?

I know that this holds if $n = 2$, but what about arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Yes. See Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I by Lazarsfeld, page 88.